# Format string dict in dict

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, format, payload, f-string

I want to have define a payload with variables, and the payload contains a dict inside a dict, like so:

```
payload = {"columns": "{x,y,z}",
           "number": "{n:123456}"}
```

I wanted ideally something like for a variable:

```
myVar = 123

payload = {"columns": "{x,y,z}",
           "number": "{n:{myVar}}"}
```

However this and other combinations doesn't work. I've tried both f-strings and formats. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
myVar = 123

payload = {"columns": "{x,y,z}", "number": f"{{n:{myVar}}}"}
print(payload)
```

---

Or:

```
payload = {"columns": "{x,y,z}", "number": "{n:" + str(myVar) + "}"}
print(payload)
```

---

Or:

```
payload = {"columns": "{x,y,z}", "number": "{{n:{}}}".format(myVar)}
print(payload)
```

All prints:

```py
{'columns': '{x,y,z}', 'number': '{n:123}'}
```